# @Document(collection = "collectionName") not working when extend another class

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am working on a spring boot application with spring data mongoDB. I have a common class which holds all the common properties and my other classes extend it so that I have those common properties in them.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
public abstract class AbstractAuditEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreatedBy
    @NotNull
    private Long createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @NotNull
    private Long updatedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @NotNull
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @NotNull
    private Instant updatedDate;
}
```

now when i extend this class in my another class like

```
@Document(collection = "consumer")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class ConsumerEntity extends AbstractAuditEntity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
}
```

The document created in mongo database has same name as my class name i.e "ConsumerEntity", how do I get @Document(collection = "consumer") to work so that in my mongo database the collection name is reflected as "consumer". Thank You

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: Note: it should work if you remove `@EntityListeners`